# How to automatically renew dapr mutual tls certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, dapr

I'm using `dapr` in `Kubernetes` with microservices, it has been one year since I installed `dapr` with `helm`, but recently microservices were down due to following error:

```bash
x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid dapr
```

So, when investigating from https://docs.dapr.io/operations/security/mtls/:

> If custom certificates have not been provided, Dapr automatically
> creates and persist self-signed certs valid for one year.

It's clear, that mtls expire one year after creation and they are managed by `daprsystem` configuration.

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
...
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: daprsystem
spec:
  metric:
    enabled: true
  mtls:
    allowedClockSkew: 15m
    enabled: true
    workloadCertTTL: 24h
```

I managed to get a new mtls certificate by removing `dapr` chart and re-installing it, but is there a renewal policy I can apply to the configuration ?

Thanks,